# Adding object value array to separate array object

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects, and and object with arrays as value. I'm trying to take the array from the object and add it as a value to a new key in the objects in the array. When you run the example below you see the object key is instead added as an array of its characters and I'm guessing I'm using `Object.values()` incorrectly?

So instead of the output being like;

```
{
    "arrkey1": "arrvalue1",
    "arrkey2": "arrvalue2",
    "newStuff": [
      "o",
      "b",
      "j",
      "k",
      "e",
      "y",
      "1"
    ]
  }
```

How do I instead get what I want like;

```
{
    "arrkey1": "arrvalue1",
    "arrkey2": "arrvalue2",
    "newStuff": [
       "objValue1",
       "objValue2",
       "objValue3"
  ]
}
```

```js
let arr1 = [
  {
  'arrkey1': 'arrvalue1',
  'arrkey2': 'arrvalue2'
  },
  {
  'arrkey3': 'arrvalue3',
  'arrkey4': 'arrvalue4'
  },
  {
  'arrkey5': 'arrvalue5',
  'arrkey6': 'arrvalue6'
  }
];

const obj1 = {
  'objkey1': [
    'objValue1',
    'objValue2',
    'objValue3'
  ],
  'objkey2': [
    'objValue4',
    'objValue5',
    'objValue6'
  ]
};

for (const item in obj1) {
  for (let i = 0, x = arr1.length; i < x; i++) {
      arr1[i].newStuff = Object.values(item);
  }
}

console.log(arr1);
```

Comment: How do you decide which property of obj1 to attach to, for example, the first element of arr1?

Comment: @James I'd have a condition in the loop to apply the right one but I'm just trying right now to get the value array from the object so I can add it as a key value to the array of objects. I don't understand why I'm getting down-voted for this....

Answer (score 0):

This example inserts a copy of `obj1.objkey1` into each element of `arr1`:

```js
let arr1 = [
  {
  'arrkey1': 'arrvalue1',
  'arrkey2': 'arrvalue2'
  },
  {
  'arrkey3': 'arrvalue3',
  'arrkey4': 'arrvalue4'
  },
  {
  'arrkey5': 'arrvalue5',
  'arrkey6': 'arrvalue6'
  }
];

const obj1 = {
  'objkey1': [
    'objValue1',
    'objValue2',
    'objValue3'
  ],
  'objkey2': [
    'objValue4',
    'objValue5',
    'objValue6'
  ]
};

const combined = arr1.map(item => ({newStuff: [...obj1.objkey1], ...item}));
console.log(combined);
```